# Are <script> tags subject to the same CORS restrictions as javascript/fetch calls?

Tags: javascript, html, http, cors, cross-browser

It's common practice to include scripts from other origins with script tags but when you use fetch calls on other origins then everything must be configured carefully other wise you will get a CORS error.

Does the script tag somehow bypass CORS? How does that work?

Comment: Are you asking why it's allowed to load the script from another origin, or are you suggesting that the remote scripts will try to fetch other data from their sites?

Comment: @Barmar the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Same Origin Policy prevents JavaScript *reading data* from other origins without permission (which is usually provided by CORS).

Running JavaScript from other origins is not prevented by the Same Origin Policy (nor is loading stylesheets, displaying images, content in iframes, etc).

JavaScript in the page can't (usually) read sensitive data from other origins through those methods in the first place.

Comment: Unless they are in a global function that can be stringified, but I guess that's up to the developers

Comment: Okay but on the http level, what happens? With a cross origin fetch made via javascript, it is denied. But when the browser does it via a script tag, it's fine?

Comment: @bluejayke — Hence “usually”.

Comment: @Thomas — Yes. The Same Origin Policy doesn’t apply so the browser doesn’t check for or add CORS headers.

Answer (score 3):

It depends, if you are trying to load a Javascript module  (i.e. <**script  type="module"** > ) then you need a CORS enabled server, if the **src** is on a different origin. Otherwise no. i.e.

```
<!-- Not a CORS request -->
<script src="https://example.com/script.js"></script>

<!-- CORS request -->
<script type="module" src="https://example.com/script.js"></script>
```

Note, you can add **crossorigin** attribute to the first one, to ask browser to treat it as a CORS request.

you can find more here : https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/